# What Hard Drive do I use with this SATA Connector?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, hard-drive, sata, compatibility

I am running Ubuntu Linux on my laptop, and I need to get new hard drive for it. This is the output from lspci showing my connector:

```
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HBM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA AHCI Controller (rev 03)
```

I need to know what hard drive to get that will match that. Does anyone know how to figure that out?>

Answer (score 3):

A laptop SATA hard drive. The speed doesn't matter terribly; either the drive or the controller will slow itself down to match the other.

Comment: I think you should mention SSD's here as well.

Comment: @Zabba: As long as it's in laptop form and it has a SATA interface, it doesn't matter whether it's a SSD or a platter drive.

Comment: Are there any other kinds of specs that we should consider (as in type 1, 2, or 3)? If we get a type 3 drive, will the extra cost benefit me any?

Comment: ICH8 only supports up to SATA 2.0. 3.0 hard drives will be reduced to 2.0 speeds.

Comment: Thanks muchly. Sorry I can't vote your answer up, I don't have the rep yet.